# Sideloading Apps on Google-TV

Tags: side-loading, google-tv

Even though a new version (which includes the android market) is coming out for the Google TV this summer, I'm a little impatient and slightly curious.

There are a few apps that I'd like to try out on the google TV that I don't think would necessarily break anything (i.e. apps that come to mind don't use sensors, camera, etc) so I'm wondering if there is a way to sideload apps into the current generation of the Google TV?

There is no support for opening APK files natively, but I wonder if I hook my computer up to the STB via USB, if I could run some adb blackmagic and inject apps into it.

Any thoughts or opinions?

And yes, I am aware the current apps out there aren't optimized for a google TV, but I'm looking to add some basic functionality to hold me over until the next version comes out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the ADBD (adb daemon) is not enabled on any current Google TV hardware, so adb connectivity is not possible via USB, Ethernet, or any other means.

However, a few crafty tinkerers from [GTVhacker](http://www.gtvhacker.com/) site managed to hack the Logitech Revue unit to enable this functionality.  Keep in mind that this is a hardware hack and includes physically opening up the Revue box and soldering connections on the motherboard.  You can read more on this mod [here](http://www.gtvhacker.com/index.php/Steps_to_get_root).  Needless to say, this hack is not for everyone, and carries even more risk of bricking the STB as a plain software hack.

Comment: Of course things can never be easy, eh? I got my Revue unit for free by being a web developer and entering their giveaway, so it wouldn't be a financial loss if I bricked it. But I have incredibly bad luck when it comes to hardware, so I think I might be just forced to wait until official support is added. Sigh.

Comment: @Foxtrot: I hear ya. I intentionally don't own a soldering iron, specifically to deter myself from ruining (expensive) hardware :)

Comment: Haha +1. Same here. Additionally to deter myself from burning down my apartment. Like I said, I have _really_ bad luck.